# How to convert a GeoJSON polygon to a list of Geohashes of a given precision in ruby?

Tags: ruby, geojson, geohashing

I'm currently working with combinations of geopoint + radius that I've successfully transformed to a GeoJSON polygon (loosing a bit of precision).
What I need now is a conversion to a list of all Geohashes that intersects with that area with a predetermined precision.

I've found [geohash-poly](https://github.com/derrickpelletier/geohash-poly) which does exactly what I want but it's in javascript/node-js rather than ruby.

Is there any equivalent in ruby out there ?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/davetroy/geohash may help.  I just did a google for `ruby geohash`

Comment: Yeah I got that one but it doesn't allow to transform anything other than a single point.

Comment: Hi, same question here. Ever found anything?

Comment: @kaboom For now I'm calling the geohash-poly as a microservice from my rails app.